DateTime to Date in Excel from MS Access and SQL Server datasources
I inherited a very old project. Currently, there is a MS Access 2019 database. This database has a DSN to a SQL Server database. There are cross tab queries in MS Access that pull data from SQL Server, and export that data to Excel.
The issue is, that dates are coming back as datetime and not date only. They are date only in SQL Server, but somewhere along the way, they are getting converted to datetime.
I have little experience in MS Access or cross tab queries. Throwing out a hail mary to see if anyone out there knows where to start, or what the fix is.
This is the connection string and query in Excel for reference:


Where is connection to SQL server? It is a connection to access db only and using ODBC. access too might be using ODBC for connecting to SQL server and using an old version that is not aware of Date data type? And if it comes in as Datetime what would be the side impact for you? You can always change its display, no? IOW, your question needs more details (and text not pictures). Did you try with OLEDB drivers? Why don't you directly connect to SQL server?

@CetinBasoz,  I believe they are linked objects with the actual data source being MSSQL.

Sorry I don't understand why you don't directly use SQL server then. (Or how do you use the above dialog)

What is the actual problem you're having in excel? can you attach the picture of the pivot or something? and what you actually want to have

Is this perhaps helpful? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/date-format-pivot-table-vs-source-data/m-p/3780198

@siggemannen,  I posted that below in an answer since I couldn't post an image here.  Columns, X, Y, Z and AA show up as DateTime format when the data is exported into excel (it is Date format in MSSQL).  But either MS Access or Excel converts it to DateTime.  So everytime they use this report, or reload the data, they have to manaully change DateTime to Date.  They would like this to come in as Date only.

somewhere along the way, they are getting converted to datetime - it should be easy for you to find exactly where this happens. Open the Access database. Open a linked table directly - does it show dates or datetime? Open the crosstab query. Check the same.

In Excel and VBA, Date and DateTime is the same numeric value. So, apply a Format where you wish to display the DateTime values as a date only.
